# adb devices return error: protocol fault (no status)

Tags: android, adb

My ADB stopped working recently.
All commands results in error: protocol fault (no status).

Follow trace.

adb devices

```
system/core/adb/adb.c::main():Handling commandline()
system/core/adb/adb_client.c::adb_query():adb_query: host:devices
system/core/adb/adb_client.c::_adb_connect():_adb_connect: host:version
system/core/adb/sysdeps_win32.c::socket_loopback_client():socket_loopback_client
: could not connect to tcp:5037
system/core/adb/adb_client.c::adb_connect():adb_connect: service host:devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
system/core/adb/adb_client.c::_adb_connect():_adb_connect: host:devices
system/core/adb/sysdeps_win32.c::socket_loopback_client():socket_loopback_client
: port 5037 type tcp => fd 101
system/core/adb/transport.c::writex():writex: fd=101 len=4: 30303063 000c
system/core/adb/transport.c::writex():writex: fd=101 len=12: 686f73743a646576696
36573 host:devices
system/core/adb/transport.c::readx():readx: fd=101 wanted=4
system/core/adb/sysdeps_win32.c::_socket_set_errno():_socket_set_errno: unhandle
d value 10054
system/core/adb/transport.c::readx():readx: fd=101 error 22: Invalid argument
system/core/adb/sysdeps_win32.c::adb_close():adb_close: 101(lo-client:5037)
system/core/adb/adb_client.c::adb_connect():adb_connect: return fd -1
error: protocol fault (no status)
```

Comment: Did you messup with ADB recently ? What did you do very recently which is resulting in this scenario ?

Comment: Good question... Nothing that I remember...
I already tried reinstall Android SDK Plataform-tools and not work.
I've tried on another port and neither work.

Comment: As we cannot guess what might have gone wrong in this case neither the error message indicates any reasonable probing, I suggest you to completely follow the new installation process from scratch. Uninstall the ADT package and re-install it again like this -  http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html All the best !

Comment: Monday i'll try these steps and comment the results.
Thanks

Comment: You can see this issue for help. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219085

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue and found the problem: Android Studio.

Open the Android Studio menu `Tools` -> `Android` and uncheck `Enable ADB integration`.

`adb devices` should work (you might need `adb kill-server` first).

Then you can re-enable ADB integration in Studio.

Answer (score 3):

This typically means, that your **ADB** service or your driver is **outdated**.
Since the drivers aren't updated most of the time, make sure you've installed the latest version of your Android SDK Platform-tools via the SDK Manager:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recently got the same error, after installing a driver for the Moto X. I previously had the ADB and Fastboot quick install. I installed the driver, saw that the Moto X still wasn't registered, so uninstalled the driver again. Ten I got this error message. I opened Task Manager, killed the ADB.exe and then in Bash hit the `adb device` command. All was good again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on `linux`. I didn't realize I had an old `adb` on my path.
Make sure that

```
which adb
```

and

```
which emulator
```

point to similar android sdk versions.