# adb error (error: protocol fault (couldn't read status): Invalid argument)

Tags: android, adb

I am unable to connect to my phone using adb.
I am getting the following error:

```
D:\softwares\Development\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>adb devices -l
List of devices attached
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
error: protocol fault (couldn't read status): Invalid argument
```

http://s18.postimg.org/7fdc8w9dl/screenshot_97.png

Previously i am getting this error in windows 8.1 then i have installed windows 10 and error resolved but now again i am unable to connect my cellphone with adb :(.

I am getting this error even if no device is connected.

Eclipse error:

```
[2015-10-24 13:25:02 - ddms] Failed to initialize Monitor Thread: Unable to establish loopback connection
[2015-10-24 13:25:02 - adb] error: protocol fault (couldn't read status): Invalid argument
[2015-10-24 13:25:02 - ddms] 'D:\softwares\Development\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
```

Update:
Even adb tcp is also not working so i think this is not a driver issue.

ADB traces
http://s24.postimg.org/mtfdwf3id/screenshot_99.png

Comment: reinstall your device drivers correctly. That may resolve this problem.

Comment: see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21049253/adb-devices-return-error-protocol-fault-no-status

Comment: I am getting this error even if no device is connected I don't think its a driver issue

Comment: try running the emulator and run the command, if its the same then its not the device, its is either your software or something else

Comment: Its also not working with emulator / Genymotion

Comment: I have also tried to download fresh adb but still result is same

Comment: You can see this issue for help. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219085

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of mentioned solutions work, seems like something wrong with windows, finally i ended up with resetting my windows 10 and issue resolved.

Comment: I have to put my smartphone in flight mode and disable the wifi on my macBook, then enable both and restart and it worked

Answer (score 7):

In my case:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

:)

Comment: This doesn't always work, it sometimes gives out a "error: failed to read response from server" if such think happens, rebooting is required.

Answer (score 6):

Although not exactly the same error as the OP, I was getting a similar error in **Windows**:

```
❯ adb.exe start-server
error: protocol fault (couldn't read status): No error
```

This error was related to my port proxy. It seems I had setup some rules that resulted in the adb client/server not being able to communicate with each other.

I was able to solve this by resetting my portproxy settings:

```
netsh interface portproxy reset
```

And now I can start the adb server:

```
❯ adb.exe start-server
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
```

Answer (score 5):

Just Restart PC and everything mean Android Studio and your android Device 
its working for me

Answer (score 3):

As you may found in source code of ADB, something raised up this error:

```
     if (!ReadFdExactly(fd, buf, 4)) {
         *error = perror_str("protocol fault (couldn't read status)");
         return false;
     }
```

Try to export 
`export ADB_TRACE=all`

And rerun `adb devices`

With this `env` variable you will see much more info

Comment: How to export ADB_TRACE ? I am using windows

Comment: @H4SN   `set ADB_TRACE=all`

Comment: where i need to set ADB_TRACE-all ?

Comment: @H4SN in `cmd` (console) before running `adb`

Comment: You have to type '=' instead of minus

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93561/discussion-between-h4sn-and-arseniy).

Comment: @ Arseniy Same problem with as admin

Comment: Finally i ended up with resetting my Windows 10 and everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I was also getting this error so here's how I solved it. I killed the adb process and start again.

#### Steps:

1. Open the **Task manager** (Windows);

   - You can press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Esc</kbd> and task  manager will be opened.
2. Find *adb.exe* and right click on it. Click the "End process" menu item;
3. Open a command prompt and type `adb start-server` and it will start the adb again.

Comment: Excelente, funcionó de maravilla, nada de reiniciar PC, Gracias

Comment: This is not a solution, even if it might work in some cases. It does not fix the cause why the issue occurs in the first place. It is just a simple retry.

Comment: IT IS a solution because explain why this is happening . Another adb process is running in zombie mode and needs to be killed

Comment: In my case, I needed to disconnect my devices before performing this solution and resolving the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In your task manager, 
find adb.exe > right click and End Process.

solved this way for me..

Answer (score 1):

You can get more info with:

```
export ADB_TRACE=all
```

This gave me the full log when connecting:

```
adb D 12-15 11:48:11  1014 18521 adb_trace.cpp:187] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
adb D 12-15 11:48:11  1014 18521 adb_trace.cpp:187] Version 30.0.2-6538114
adb D 12-15 11:48:11  1013 18519 adb_client.cpp:155] _adb_connect: host:connect:192.168.1.109
adb D 12-15 11:48:11  1013 18519 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=3 len=30 30303161686f73743a636f6e6e656374 001ahost:connect [truncated]
adb D 12-15 11:48:11  1013 18519 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=3 wanted=4
adb D 12-15 11:48:11  1013 18519 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4 4f4b4159 OKAY
adb D 12-15 11:48:11  1013 18519 adb_client.cpp:189] _adb_connect: return fd 3
adb D 12-15 11:48:11  1013 18519 adb_client.cpp:364] adb_connect: return fd 3
adb D 12-15 11:48:11  1013 18519 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=3 wanted=4
adb D 12-15 11:48:11  1013 18519 adb_io.cpp:91] readx: fd=3 disconnected
error: protocol fault (couldn't read status length): Undefined error: 0
```

I resolved the issue by updating my Platform Tools from the SDK Manager in Android Studio.

```
$ adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 30.0.5-6877874
```

Comment: This is cool, thanks for sharing. I was wanting some more debug output to see what was happening. Looked up the source code:
https://github.com/hadess/adbd/blob/master/adb/adb_trace.cpp
I can't explain why, but after a day and a half of not being able to pair, after I ran this export statement to get more logs, I can pair and connect. I really can't believe that just asking for more log output could have fixed any issue I was having, but, this is just what I'm experiencing right now.

Answer (score 1):

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70490543/1235675), for me adb port `5037` was in use, killing the process using the port resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall and re-install ADB from Android Studio and check your path to make sure you aren't pointing to any other ADB installations.

I had no other installations but for some reason the ADB instance I had was corrupted (v `1.0.41`).

I went to Preferences >> Android SDK >> Unchecked the installed version >> Clicked next to uninstall.

Then I went back and re-checked the box to install it again and it worked.  Still version `1.0.41`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after updating android studio.

None of the above solutions are worked.

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools

**I solved it by downloading `platform-tools` from the above link. And replaced the contents of my android SDK's platform-tools with downloaded one**

Answer (score -1):

Go to SDK Tools in Android studio uncheck the old platform versions, then check the latest one and apply.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

In my case:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

then (can change port `5555` with preferred port):

```
adb tcpip 5555
```

which results in: `restarting in TCP mode port: 5555`

issue resolved

Answer (score -1):

adb.exe: protocol fault (couldn't read status): connection reset

adb kill-server
adb start-server

This helped in my case.

Comment: This answer is a duplicate. Someone has already posted same answer.