# Android emulator error (AdbHostServer.cpp: 83)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I run my program on android studio but I having problems with the emulator, the problem is as follows:

```
Emulator: emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp: 83: adb protocol fault (couldn't read status length)
```

I did not find any solution, noting that I deleted the Emulator and reset it again and it did not succeed, and also I closed the device and restarted it and it did not work

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [adb error (error: protocol fault (couldn't read status): Invalid argument)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316006/adb-error-error-protocol-fault-couldnt-read-status-invalid-argument)