# adb.exe: failed to check server version: protocol fault (status 00 1b ffffffd0 02?!)

Tags: windows, adb

I can't figure out this issue with android debug bridge (not working at all).

On a Windows 10 PC

platform-tools_r33.0.3-windows downloaded and unzipped folder "platform-tools" in C: (from https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-windows.zip)

Added system variable "Path" : "C:\platform-tools" in Environment variables

I run cmd as admin, then adb and get:

Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41

Version 33.0.3-8952118

Installed as C:\platform-tools\adb.exe

[...all options...]

ISSUE:

any command for adb (e.g. "adb devices") results into:

"adb.exe: failed to check server version: protocol fault (status 00 1b ffffffd0 02?!)"

FAILED ATTEMPTS:

restart PC

kill-server / start-server

uninstall - reinstall adb

running adb from different directories (C:, C/platform-tools, other)

with an android device plugged in or not

removing C:\platform-tools from Path

adding C:\platform-tools to user Path (instead of system AND concurrently)

Comment: Adb does not admin permission to run. What Windows version do you use? First time ,out start adb it spawns itself as adb server which continues to run in background and manages communication between devices and adb command line client. This happens automatically but on your system it fails to check if there is already a server instance running. I would start with rebooting the system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [adb error (error: protocol fault (couldn't read status): Invalid argument)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316006/adb-error-error-protocol-fault-couldnt-read-status-invalid-argument)